# Keycloak Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue

Tags: keycloak

I am not find proper solution for below error in online.

Redirected from: http://localhost:8085/MYAPP/sb/test?cid=1c09ac7eb4994be1b91908c38b734042

from origin: http://localhost:8085

Has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header is present on the requested resource.

Note:- My project is RCP based and Keycloak tomcat adapter

I have tried to add enable cors true in keycloak json file and below is my keycloak json file

```
{
  "realm": "REALM",
  "auth-server-url": "https://{{server}}/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "MYCLIENT",
  "public-client": true,
  "enable-cors" : true,
  "cors-max-age" : 1000,
  "cors-allowed-methods" : "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET",
 "cors-exposed-headers" : "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers",
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```